# How can i show a message pop up like Play Music app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I want to add bar like Play Music app of google shows in the their application. I want to use that same animation effect as they are doing. So Can any one guide me that is there any open source code to add this functionality in the app or i need to code it all manually, any guide will be helpful, I search net but i did not found any.

[image]

Comment: Where is the pop up message in your photo?

Comment: down at the bottom, rouded by red rectangle in the image

Comment: i know its a UIView added above the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) UILabel *popupLabel;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (UILabel *)popupLabel
{
    if( !_popupLabel ) {
        CGFloat height = 44.0;
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                   self.view.bounds.size.height - height,
                                                                   self.view.bounds.size.width,
                                                                   height)];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.alpha = 0.0;
        [self.view addSubview:label];

        _popupLabel = label;
    }
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_popupLabel];
    return _popupLabel;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self performSelector:@selector(showWithMessage:) withObject:@"1 song added to playlist" afterDelay:2.0];

}

- (void)showWithMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    self.popupLabel.text = message;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.popupLabel.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}

- (void)hide
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.popupLabel.alpha = 0.0;
    }];
}
```